# How to expand command-line arguments when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to make Visual Studio expand `*` in file names (and directory names) before invoking the debugger? When I write, e.g., `*.txt` as the command line arguments, the `args[]` variable will contain just one entry (`"*.txt"`), rather than one entry for each matching file. Do I have to write my own code to do this expansion?

Comment: That's a pretty infamous Unix shell feature.  It is completely absent in Windows, in VS as well.

Comment: Well, it works in `cmd`, so it's not completely absent. Anyway, I solved it by simply creating a list of all the files I needed, and assigning the list to `args` at the beginning of my debugging session. But it's kind of fiddly, and such an obvious thing that VS should support IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are invoking visual studio as such:

> devenv /debugexe 'myprogram' *.txt

then yes, `args[]` will contain `'*.txt'` and you will need to parse and respond to that in your program. (Just the same as if you'd launched the program without the debugger).

Comment: Actually, no, I invoke the debugger by hitting F5, after entering the arguments under "Project properties" -> "Debug" -> "Command Line Arguments". And I do not surround them with quotation marks.